# Sequelize. Error when connecting to mysql. "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I installed and configured mysql following [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-22-04).

In addition I changed the `bind-address` from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` in the `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file to be able to connect from my pc via workbrench.

This is my sequalize code:

```js
import { Sequelize, DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { logger } from "../utils/index.js";

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  dialect: "mysql",
  logging: (msg) => logger(msg, "database"),
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', error);
});
```

.env:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=someuser
DP_PASS=Somepassword@
DB_PORT=3306
DB_NAME=dbname
```

Error log after npm run start:

```
Unable to connect to the database:  AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:94:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
    at async /home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32 {
  parent: Error: Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
      at Packet.asError (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
    sql: undefined
  },
  original: Error: Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
      at Packet.asError (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
    sql: undefined
  }
}
node:internal/process/esm_loader:97
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

AccessDeniedError [SequelizeAccessDeniedError]: Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:94:17)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:222:24)
    at async /home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32 {
  parent: Error: Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
      at Packet.asError (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
    sql: undefined
  },
  original: Error: Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
      at Packet.asError (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/packet.js:728:17)
      at ClientHandshake.execute (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:478:34)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:97:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/api/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:104:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
      at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
    code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
    errno: 1045,
    sqlState: '28000',
    sqlMessage: "Access denied for user 'someuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)",
    sql: undefined
  }
}
```

I run the application on the same machine as the database.

Through MYSQL Workbrench I connected without any problems.

Nodejs packages: `sequelize 6.33.0`, `mysql2 3.6.2`

Mysql version: `mysql  Ver 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.23.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

Comment: Typo in .env?  `DP_PASS` - did you mean `DB_PASS`?

Comment: @RobEyre omg, thanks for noticing, that was the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mentioned by Rob Eyre change
DP_PASS=Somepassword@
to
DB_PASS=Somepassword@